# Performing Fetch Request in a Loop

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am working on an application that returns a list of ids from first fetch request. After getting the ids, I have to loop through the ids and get details of each item and then display it on the screen.

```
  fetch(TOP_STORIES)
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(storyIds){
      // storyIds is [22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,123,213,342,45456,778,888]
      // is this the best way to fetch all the details of the story
      storyIds.forEach(function(storyId){

        let storyDetailsURL = `https://someurl/v0/item/${storyId}.json?print=pretty`

        fetch(storyDetailsURL)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((story) => {
            displayStory(story)
        })
      })

  })
```

My question is that is looping the best way to get the results?

UPDATE: Promise.all is giving me issues:

[image]

UPDATE: Using Async and Await

```
async function fetchTopHeadlinesAsyncAwait() {

  let response = await fetch(TOP_STORIES)
  let storyIds = await response.json()

  for(let storyId of storyIds) {
    console.log(storyId)
    let storyDetailsURL = `someurl/er/tg/${storyId}.json?print=pretty`
    let response = await fetch(storyDetailsURL)
    let story = await response.json()
    displayStory(story)
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't like it because it hammers the server with all requests at once. It would usually be better to request them one at a time. To do that, I define and index and make a function called next() that fetches a single item by id. next() checks the index to see if it's the last one. If not, increment the index and call next(), otherwise stop and do something else. Don't forget to call next() manually once at the bottom of the containing context...

Comment: by the way, if you switch to using *async* / *await* style code instead of *Promise.then*, it would *clean up* nicely and be more convenient to use.  *Promises* are great though.  Other than than getting the story detail only when needed is what I would do.

Comment: Can you try just remove the json() function line ?

Comment: @BjarneGerhardt-Pedersen If I remove json() then how will I get json from the response?

Comment: ahh, async/await.  so much cleaner.

Comment: @johndoe i updated my answer so json should now work with the array of promises. The .json() didnt work, because it was called on the array of responses.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Promise.all functionality to fetch a list of async actions. They will be completed when all are successful.

Here is example of your code with Promise all, let me know how it works :)

```
const fetchStories = () => {
  let response = await fetch(TOP_STORIES);
  let storyIds = await response.json();

    let urls = [];
    storyIds.forEach(function(storyId) {
      urls.push(`https://someurl/v0/item/${storyId}.json?print=pretty`);
    });

    Promise.all(
      urls.map(url =>
        fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .catch(err => console.error(err))
      )
    ).then(stories => stories.forEach(story => displayStory(story)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In your code if one of the promises fail does it abort everything or does it still gets the ones which are successful.

Comment: Hi, If one promise fail, they will all fail, using this technique.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I want that since I am pulling news articles and if one fails then I don't want everything to fail.

Comment: use Promise.any instead in a loop