# How do I get file name when set file object to dropzone js?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

With a list array of image name and its url, I tried to set a dropzone to upload these image files, but I was unable to get individual file name for the dropzone.

Here is I tried:

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#myDropzone', {
    url: 'http://localhost/Upload/',
  })

  upload = Dropzone.forElement("#myDropzone");
  imageList = ["Rabbit-Island-beach-850x478.jpg", "Rabbit-Island-Pier-1-850x478.jpg"]
  url = "https://blog.camboticket.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/"

  for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
    image_url = url + imageList[i]
    console.log(imageList[i])
    fetch(image_url)
      .then(res => res.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        // mime = blob['type'].toString().split('/')[0]
        // ext = blob['type'].toString().split('/')[1]
        // let file = new File([blob], blob.size+'.'+ext, blob);
        let file = new File([blob], imageList[i], blob);
        upload.addFile(file);
      });

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- dropzone cdn -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.6/min/dropzone.min.js" integrity="sha512-KgeSi6qqjyihUcmxFn9Cwf8dehAB8FFZyl+2ijFEPyWu4ZM8ZOQ80c2so59rIdkkgsVsuTnlffjfgkiwDThewQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.6/dropzone.min.css" integrity="sha512-jU/7UFiaW5UBGODEopEqnbIAHOI8fO6T99m7Tsmqs2gkdujByJfkCbbfPSN4Wlqlb9TGnsuC0YgUgWkRBK7B9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></div>
```

As see here, the file name is undefined. How can I get a correct file name here? Because I get it in order submit to server with correct file name? Thanks.

[image]

**P.S:** I tried to get file name via `imageList[i]` but did not work in `fetch()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of trying, I managed to find solution by myself through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169313/performing-fetch-request-in-a-loop/55169496) by using `Promise.all()`.

Here it is:

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#myDropzone', {
    url: 'http://localhost/Upload/',
  })

  upload = Dropzone.forElement("#myDropzone");
  imageList = ["Rabbit-Island-beach-850x478.jpg", "Rabbit-Island-Pier-1-850x478.jpg"]
  url = "https://blog.camboticket.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/"

  var tmp = 0;

  let urls = []

  for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
    image_url = url + imageList[i]
    urls.push(image_url);
  }

  Promise.all(
    urls.map(url =>
      fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.blob())
      .then(blob => {

        name = url.split('/')[url.split('/').length - 1]
        // name = name[name.length - 1]
        let file = new File([blob], name, blob);
        upload.addFile(file);
      })
    ))




});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- dropzone cdn -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.6/min/dropzone.min.js" integrity="sha512-KgeSi6qqjyihUcmxFn9Cwf8dehAB8FFZyl+2ijFEPyWu4ZM8ZOQ80c2so59rIdkkgsVsuTnlffjfgkiwDThewQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.6/dropzone.min.css" integrity="sha512-jU/7UFiaW5UBGODEopEqnbIAHOI8fO6T99m7Tsmqs2gkdujByJfkCbbfPSN4Wlqlb9TGnsuC0YgUgWkRBK7B9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></div>
```

It works perfectly fine for me, and I hope it does the same for people who have the same issue like me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

run js console `Dropzone.getElement("form_id")`
then
Which element do you want to get
`Dropzone.getElement("#x").getElementsByClassName("dz-filename")[0].innerText`